# How to refer to a report's control via a form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report that can be opened from two different forms, and depending on from which form it is opened, it's title should be changed. For example, if I press the print button on the other form, then it refers to the report it's about to print and uses Label.Caption to change the title.

Does anyone have insight on this?

Comment: You'd need to provide more information, including examples of the related code you've tried, and why it's not working.  Also, instead of trying to change a report from elsewhere, why not have the report title change based on how it was opened?  (see @Gustav's answer below)

Comment: Also, note that the report has to be open before you can refer to the controls on it, and I think you can't change controls until it's in Design Mode.  Here's the documentation on [the `Report.Controls` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/access.report.controls). Note that it's read-only;

Answer (score 2):

When you open the form, call it using the parameter *OpenArgs* (the last parameter):

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "YourReportName",,,,, Me.Name
```

Read that when the report is opened:

```
Private Sub Report_Load()

    Me.Caption = Nz(Me.OpenArgs)

End Sub
```